# Typescript Model declaration - Is there a way to provide the iterative key based without hardcoding each value in model file?

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, interface, model

We are having a situation that in one of the database table contains the indexed kind of column names (example: name, id, address, details_column_1, details_column_2, detail_column_3, …details_column_n).
This database column has been used by some existing applications so changing the existing table structure of better naming is not possible. Secondly, we have similar situation in more than 1 tables.

We are getting the WEB API response for the same table is something like below.

```
{
    name: ‘xyz’,
    id: 123456,
    address: [‘address lines’],
    details_column_1: [], 
    details_column_2: [], 
    detail_column_3: [], 
    …
    …
    details_column_n: []
}
```

Now trying to create an interface model for this in Typescript now and end up with doing based on the number of repeated similar items the model is growing like

```
export interface ClientDetails {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: array | null;
    detail_column_1: array | null;
    detail_column_2: array | null;
    detail_column_3: array | null;
    …
    …
    detail_column_n: array | null;
}
```

Is there a way to provide the iterative key based without hardcoding each value in model file?
Note: Modifying the existing application columns are responses are not possible. Looking for any option with simple model definition for the these kind of values (we have update 50 columns like this).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way - though you will need to use [TypeScript 4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-rc/).

#### 1. Create Number range for `n`

TypeScript does not support [number range types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480) yet. So we will generate one programmatically.

```
range = n => Array.from({length:n},
  (_,i) => i === 0 ? `type Range = ${i}` : `|${i}`).join("")

range(5) // for n=5 detail columns
// or
copy(range(5)) // with Firefox: copy type directly to clipboard
```

executed in the browser console will give you:

```
type Range = 0|1|2|3|4
```

#### 2. Create `ClientDetails`

```
export interface ClientDetails extends RepeatGroup {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: Array<unknown> | null;
}

type RepeatGroup = { [K in `detail_column_${Range}`]: Array<unknown> | null }

declare const t1: ClientDetails
t1.id // number
t1.detail_column_1 // unknown[] | null
t1.detail_column_4 // unknown[] | null
```

[Here is a playground sample.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201108#code/C4TwDgpgBASghgOwObQLxQAxQD5QIw5QBMhAzIQCwBQVEAHmAPYBOwUAlgsBMwGZwBjaAGEANuwhcAIhGBx2ogM5R63BABNlMCJDjAA4s0YBXMFADeVKNY7qAXFATGAtgCMeAbis2EcZxAdFYGZOJC8bKDh1dWYIRUUHAEFmZjgQAB5jBABrBEYAdwQAPkInUVEvAF8aUEhYHQg9QxMzdHMoAG0AaQ4EKAADdVl5UQB9AUZRFwRRgBJzeGQISv6AXSSUtMycvMKS3DLRKGqqIYFROFioCYQgqGA8BzEJaWGFRSoHgDp2dSgAen%20jhc7mYnzwXyGcgU40m01GBEBUCyuQKCA6q1KxnK4MhbzGEymzhmFABQJRu3RmIO2NEQA)

Note: If TS 4.1 is not feasible, you could also use above technique or the TS compiler API to generate the whole `ClientDetails` type.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Ours are not yet upgraded to 4.1, will try using TS complier API as suggested will update here.